# EDIT the Azure databrics cluster's SPARK configuration using PowerShell and REST API

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-databricks

I am trying to EDIT the Azure databrics cluster's SPARK configuration using PowerShell and REST API. However I am getting an error which I am unable to understand/fix. I have provided the 'required' fields as parameters, however, the error states that I haven't passed them

CODE:

```
$DBAPIRootUrl = "dec" # example: https://uksouth.azuredatabricks.net
$DBAPIKey = "abc" # Example dapi601e67891a9d1f7886e40916479aaa

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$ClustersAPIListUrl = $DBAPIRootUrl.Trim('/') + "/api/2.0/clusters/list"
$ClustersAPIEditUrl = $DBAPIRootUrl.Trim('/') + "/api/2.0/clusters/edit"


$headers = @{
  Authorization = "Bearer $DBAPIKey"
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ClustersAPIListUrl -Method GET -Headers $headers #-Body $parameters
$json_response = ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)


$jsonDoc = [pscustomobject]@{
    cluster_id = $json_response.clusters.cluster_id
    spark_version = $json_response.clusters.spark_version
    node_type_id = $json_response.clusters.node_type_id
    spark_conf = "
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword 
datanucleus.fixedDatastore false
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL jdbc:sqlserver://metadatasrvr.database.windows.net:1433;database=emptydb
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll true
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.schema.verification false
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema true
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars maven
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 1.2.0
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName"
}

$jsonDoc | ConvertTo-Json

#$parameters | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ClustersAPIEditUrl -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $jsonDoc
```

ERROR:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Missing required fields: cluster_id, size"}
At line:21 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ClustersAPIEditUrl -Method POST - ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly explains ""error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Missing required fields: **cluster_id, size**"}".

**Note:** While editing Databricks cluster, make sure to pass the "cluster_id" and "node_type_id" as a mandatory expecting  fields.

To Edit the configuration of a cluster to match the provided attributes and size.

**An example request:**

```
{
 "cluster_id": "1202-211320-brick1",
 "num_workers": 10,
 "spark_version": "5.3.x-scala2.11",
 "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2"
}
```

**Reference:** [Databricks - REST API EDIT clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--edit)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already passed the details: spark_version = $json_response.clusters.spark_version
    node_type_id = $json_response.clusters.node_type_id

Comment: Could you please cross check the parameter format, because the error message says "Invalid_parameter_value"?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I was not saving the JSON after converting. "$jsonDoc | ConvertTo-Json" TO "$jsonDoc = $jsonDoc | ConvertTo-Json"

Comment: Can you also help me with converting "string" to "SparkConfPair" to pass the string data to "spark_conf" attribute.

Invoke-WebRequest : {"error_code":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Could not parse request object: Expected object for field spark_conf, found STRING"}